# How do I configure git to use multiple SSH keys for different accounts on a Mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, git, github

I have two GitHub accounts, one for work and one for personal use.

Due to IT requirements at work, I've been using SSH for several years, but for my personal project I've been using basic authentication because it's easier.

GitHub [deprecated basic authentication](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/), so I want to use an SSH key for my personal project now.

I already know how to [create SSH keys and associate them with my GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), but I'm only allowed to associate an SSH key with one account. So I created a second SSH key and associated it with my personal account, but now when I clone my personal repos my git client is trying to use my work SSH key instead of my personal key.

How do I configure my personal repos to use my personal SSH key and my work repos to use my work key?

I'm using a Mac.

Comment: This doesn't really matter, but I think it's interesting to point out: I got a gold badge for 10,000 views today. But Q+A combined has only received 25 votes, meaning roughly 0.25% of viewers have left any feedback. This isn't abnormal, but it does make me wonder if the answers to the question aren't working for most folks. Maybe I'll clarify that I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure your personal repos to use an SSH "alias" (which I'm calling it for simplicity's sake).

Let’s say you have two repos, `work-repo` and `magnum-opus-repo` (which, when you finish it someday, will forever change how humanity bit blits bitmaps).

First, start out by running `git remote -v` in the command line for your work repo. You’ll see something like the following:

```
origin  git@github.com:day-job-co/work-repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:day-job-co/work-repo.git (push)
```

That prefix before the colon, `git@github.com:`, is telling your SSH client the host and user name to use when logging in to GitHub. (NOTE: When using git, you MUST use the `git` username. Your actual username will always be denied access.)

However, you can alias that prefix! Open `~/.ssh/config` and you might see something like the following:

```
Host github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/day-job-co
   UseKeychain yes
```

*(If you don't already have a config file at that location, or for more detailed information about the format, see https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/)*

This is telling the SSH client to use your `~/.ssh/day-job-co` SSH key file when connecting to the `github.com` host.

If you want to use a different key file, then you can easily add an alias like so:

```
Host github-personal
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
   User git
   HostName github.com
   UseKeychain yes
```

Note that when creating an alias, you’ll need to explicitly specify the actual `User` (MUST be `git`) and `HostName` (MUST be `github.com`).

Now, in your personal repo, run `git origin -v` and, if you haven't changed it yet, you'll probably see something like:

```
origin  https://github.com/bit-blitter/magnum-opus-repo.git
```

You are going to need to change this URL to use SSH instead, but rather than the default `git@github.com:` prefix, you will instead use the alias you’ve created: `github-personal`.

Run the following command in your magnum opus repo:

```
git remote set-url "origin" "github-personal:bit-blitter/magnum-opus-repo"
```

When git uses SSH to login, it will find the `github-personal` alias, use the configured `User` and `HostName`, `git@github.com` and the SSH identity key file for your personal project, `~/.ssh/personal`.

Finally, that last configuration item, `UseKeychain yes` is totally optional. It just lets you bypass typing in your SSH password every time you push/pull/fetch/etc.

This is just one way you can configure your repos, but it's pretty easy and straightforward to setup and maintain.

Comment: thanks! to set remote it just should contain `origin` as name:  `git remote set-url origin "github-personal:...`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, except I had to delete the "UseKeychain" line.    The "origin" with quotes worked.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

### My use-case:

- I have private and work GitHub accounts.
- Accounts can also be members of organizations, but they do not all belong to the same ones.
- I also have accounts on GitLab and others.
- I structure all my code to be in `~/work/` and here I can differentiate even more with subfolders e.g., `~/work/priv/`, `~/work/comp1/`, `~/work/comp2/`, etc. This However is not the structure that must be followed.
  It can also be: `~/my_private_account/` and ~/my_work_account`, or whatever you like.
- I am only using SSH to pull/push the code.

### My Solution

The solution is to create a custom `.gitconfig` file with conditional includes for the specific configurations. It this case, different accounts.

More patterns and further reading can be found in the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes).

My `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[user]
  name = Dusan Milojkovic
  email = dusan.milojkovic@my-example-email.com

;   START CUSTOM CONFIG BLOCK FOR PRIVATE ACCOUNT

; include for all repositories inside $HOME/work/priv/
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/priv/"]
  ; The import is relative to the importer (this file)
  ; But, it can also be an absolute path
  path = .gitconfig-dmilojkovic.inc

;   END CUSTOM CONFIG BLOCK FOR PRIVATE ACCOUNT


;   START CUSTOM CONFIG BLOCK FOR WORK ACCOUNT

; include for all repositories inside $HOME/work/comp1/
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/comp1/"]
  ; The import is relative to the importer (this file)
  ; But, it can also be an absolute path
  path = .gitconfig-comp1.inc

;   END CUSTOM CONFIG BLOCK FOR WORK ACCOUNT
```

The conditionally included `~/.gitconfig-dmilojkovic.inc`

```
[core]
  SshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key_for_private_account"
```

The conditionally included `~/.gitconfig-comp1.inc`

```
[core]
  SshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key_for_work_account"
[user]
  name = dmilojkovic
  email = dmilojkovic@my-other-email.com
```

The trick is in the `SshCommand =`  which defines the exact SSH key to use for all repositories in the subfolders. Keep the `IncludeIf` statement at the last position in the `.gitconfig` file, since the last read variable will be the one that git will use, but the conditional includes will not affect one-another if you don't nest one inside another.

So I can now create custom `.gitconfig-<ACCOUNT_NAME>.inc` files with different SSH Key for different account and whatever other overrides I need, and create a new `IncludeIf` statement that will be conditionally included only if my condition is met.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer. This is a bit more complex, but a much more satisfying solution when working with a large number of repositories (such that configuring each individually would be onerous).